# Join DataFrames using Regular Expressions with PySpark

Tags: regex, join, dataframe, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I'm looking for a way to combine two DataFrames by key. My DataFrames look like this :

```
df1 :
[Row(account_uid=u"_guid_P3p2_4VlUa1taKzzYUlDkC1gv0xe3GE9DDr4IWK1P6Y=^facebook^TRUE^TRUE^FALSE^FALSE^62.36^fr_FR^facebook^10210866419602223^f^20^1996-02-21^Aude^TRUE^FALSE^fr_FR^2016-10-09^2016-10-04, work_titles=None, work_locations=None, d_date=u'2016-10-10'),
 Row(account_uid=u"_guid_Kq6LT407kBCAw0Q2K7y-Q8RxamuAgs9v_w2LINQ2jRk=^facebook^TRUE^TRUE^FALSE^TRUE^30.85^fr_FR^facebook^10153156407710064^f^29^1987-02-19^Olivia^TRUE^FALSE^fr_FR^2016-10-09^2016-09-28, work_titles=None, work_locations=None, d_date=u'2016-10-10')]

df2 :
[Row(gigyaid=u'_guid_P3p2_4VlUa1taKzzYUlDkC1gv0xe3GE9DDr4IWK1P6Y=', kruxuserids=u'K0EYsC88')]
```

My keys will be "account_uid" for df1 and "gigyaid" for df2. My code :

```
df1.join(df2, df1.account_uid == df2.gigyaid, 'fullouter')
```

In reality, my Dataframes were two RDDs, and after conversion to Datafarmes, I got Dataframes with two types of separators : "," and "^". So the problem is that the join don't take only **"_guid_P3p2_4VlUa1taKzzYUlDkC1gv0xe3GE9DDr4IWK1P6Y="** as account_uid, but all the string, from ***guid*** until **2016-10-04**, which is wrong.
I want to select the right account_uid with a regex.
I want to do something like this :

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import udf, col 
from pyspark.sql.types import StringType

contains = udf(lambda x: re.match(r'^(.*?)\^', x), BooleanType())

df = (df1.join(df2)
.where(contains(col('account_uid'), col('gigyaid'))))
```

I got this error message :

[image]

Is this possible ?
And where can I put the join's type 'fullouter' ?
Any help appreciated. Thx !

Answer (score 0):

To fix that error your udf should get two parameters and it does need to use regular expressions, for example:

```
contains = udf(lambda long, short: short in long, BooleanType())
```

But this won't be efficient as it needs to compute this python function for every pair of `df1` and `df2` elements. Instead of creating cartesian join and filtering you can use `regexp_extract` to clean the joining key:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import regexp_extract
df1.withColumn("extracted_guid", regexp_extract('account_uid', '(^[^^]*)', 1))
```

And then perform classic inner join of dataframes.